Is freedom of the mind incompatible with freedom of the body?
Before gravity was known, people could imagine having a super power to fly in the sky, which is a kind of freedom of thought, our minds do not have to be bound by knowledge.
But the real realization of human flight in the sky, it is after understanding the knowledge of gravity. We build airplanes that escape gravity, and thus achieve physical freedom.
So we can say that while knowledge gives the human body great freedom to recognize and overcome obstacles, our minds are regulated by knowledge, and those freer and more pleasant thoughts become less and less as knowledge increases.
Of course, you could say that new knowledge helps us to expand the boundaries of our understanding and see the wider and even infinite universe. But I would say that these ways of knowing are bound by logic.
After the knowledge of gravity and so on, all fantasies about flying must follow the logic of gravity, otherwise you yourself will be the first to reject those foolish thoughts from your mind.
Although knowledge can make our bodies more free, it makes our minds unconsciously enter into logical bondage.
Why is art often distorted? Perhaps art is the discontent and struggle of our free will against the constraints of logic.
So, what do you think about this problem? Whether the increase of knowledge limits our freedom of thought or expands it. Is freedom of the mind contradictory to freedom of the body?

Most sci-fi and fantasy isn't bounded by what we know to be physically possible. In fact, not being bound by that is one of the defining characteristics of those things (there is a question of suspension of disbelief, but this tends to be fairly easily addressed by e.g. just calling something "magic").

@NotThatGuy The word magic is at least 1,000 years old, but 1,000 years ago it was certainly treated differently than it is now. A thousand years ago, most people would have believed in magic, but now it's the opposite. Isn't that right?

You're talking about imaginings and fantasies and art, which doesn't require you to believe the things being imagined are actually possible, which was my point.

@MikeSong these days Very Serious People don't ever believe in magic, destiny, and the will of God. They just believe in Sufficiently Advanced Technology, the Right Side of History, and Cosmic Justice.

Oh, and naturalistic determinism. Which is totally different from destiny. Because, you see, silence you insolent peasant, I have a Ph.D, that's why.

@gs Determinism = reality consistently follows certain physical laws. "Destiny" = guiding influence of pseudo-conscious entity who's particularly concerned with what happens to humans. Kinda weird that you're suggest that those are similar or the same. And appealing to expertise is not always fallacious.

Oh, and ascribing personal agency and a strong sense of civic duty to Nature. Which is totally different from referring to Nature as a person. Totally different, you insolent peasant.

The premises of the question are all over the place. We still imagine people flying in the sky long after gaining knowledge of gravity, superman was invented in the XXth century after all. Ancient people who had no knowledge of gravity still perfectly understood the dangers of jumping from a cliff. Airplanes are not the "real realization of human flight", as what we can do by the means of our body hasn't changed at all, we still need a working plane and out bodies aren't much more free for it.

"There is no Frigate like a Book, to take us lands away, nor Courser like a page of prancing Poetry. This Traverse may the poorest take, without oppress of toll, how frugal is the Chariot that bears the human Soul!" - Emily Dickinson. The body, on the other hand, is Draconian in its continual requirements and "the thousand natural shocks the flesh is heir to."

@Scott Rowe I think Emily Dickinson is right, but the dissatisfaction of many writers and philosophers with reason and knowledge throughout history is not without reason.
And books are not equal to knowledge. In the past when rationality and knowledge were not yet developed, it seems that poetry was also more romantic.

Whether fiction or nonfiction with errors, up to now, books were the best and most accessible source of learning and practice in thought. Writing is also extraordinarily helpful, and so writing frequently and at length is something I recommend. Lifting weights isn't 'truly' lifting anything, but it beats being idle for fitness.
